# How to make rounded corners from shapes drawn with lines?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke, line-art

I am trying to make a shape like this:

[image: http://121clicks.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/qapart4_mamiyac330.jpg]

And so far in Illustrator, I've drawn this:

[image: shape]

Now, I know how to make a rectangle/square rounded. Select object, go to <kbd>Effect -> Stylize -> Rounded corners...</kbd>

But, when I select them all (except the rectangle) and do this process, it does nothing. Possibly because I've drawn the lines individually.

[image: selected]

Can anyone explain and/or advise a way to get them rounded?

Comment: If each one of those segments is a separate line and none of them are actually connected... then yes. That's your problem with the Rounded Corners Effect.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The pen tool is going to be better rather than drawing each line individually.

However, you can take your paths and combine them into a single path by selecting them and going to:

**Object → Path → Join** or **Right Click → Join**

and then you can round that path by going to:

**Effect → Stylize → Round Corners**

Alternatively, once the paths are combined you can individually select the points and adjust the corners however you'd like using the pen tool.

Answer (score 11):

Add an anchor point to one of the line segments, say, the vertical segment, at a specific distance seen from the corner anchor point (p1), and then use the Direct Selection Tool (white arrow in the tool panel) to move the original corner point the same distance along the other line segment.

Then choose the Convert Anchor Point tool (Shift-C) and click on the new point in order to convert it into a curve anchor point – keep the mouse button pressed while you drag down the handle that will come out of the point. Drag that handle down until it's on the same level with the other line. You'll see how the curve develops… (Keep the Shift key pressed as well while you drag, to make sure the dragging is perfectly straight.)

[image]

(The other slightly round corners were probably made simply by using the Round Joint and Round Caps button in the Stroke panel.)

Comment: Up voted. But due to how I have done it in the first place, it wasn't the answer.

Comment: It's taken me years to get a grip on the pen tool. Today I'm actually using it for a project and its making me finally learn it. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 8):

As Johannes mentioned, Joining or using the pen tool is the way to go.

You don't need to go to round corners from effects.

(Once you've joined the lines, or made them with the pen tool)

You can set the stroke to automatically round the corners.

Open the strokes panel (**Window → Stroke** or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>)

And set the corners to *Round Join*

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to get the *end* of the line to be rounded?  **Edit:** Ah I see it, it is in the `Cap` option.

Answer (score 6):

Well basically, what *Effect -> Stylize -> Rounded corners* do, is, that it takes closed paths (i.e. that box would most likely work) and round their corners.

Since your aim is to have kind of rounded corners on the path (body of the camera), the solution for you is to go to stroke panel (properties), increase stroke width, and in the options there, you can choose the style, how path ends and corners should look like.

[image: Stroke options (may look a bit different depending on your Ai's version)]

Hope it helps. If anything, contact me

Comment: I also tried this but it didn't work. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW -- as of Illustrator V27.0.1 shapes created with the pen tool can have their corners radiused like any other shape via the direct selection tool.

1. Select object to which the corner radii are to be applied.
2. Wait for the radius drag icon appears.
3. Click and drag to your preference.

Very convenient nowadays.

Comment: Things have moved on since 10 years ago!